# Wordpress Category URL name instead of slug

Tags: php, wordpress, url, woocommerce

Im am using woocommerce and I have categories.
When user goes to categories page there are also subcategories and 3rd lvl subcategories.

I am using `get_category_link($category->term_id);` in my template to get to the next subcategory but it returns slug instead of name

So if he clicks on category URL looks like this

Current output:

`http://example.com/category/4/4-1/4-1-1/`

where
`4 = category`
`4-1 = child category`
`4-1-1 = grandchild category`

numbers are slugs but I want that category name is represented in URL

My desired output is:

`http://example.com/category/food/fruits/berries/`

I have tried `rewrite_rules_array` and `term_link` and none of them seems to do any changes.

Any ideas?

[image]
[image]

Comment: does woocommerce not just follow the permalink structures?

Comment: did you set this on your permalinks inside admin dashboard?

Comment: show the screenshots of the permalinks page of woordpress

Comment: @Stender Im not sure. I am useing `get_category_link($category->term_id); ` to get the link to the next subcategory

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile no I did not

Comment: @Davis go to settings on the admin dashboard then select permalinks and select option that say `page name` I think

Comment: @SagarTamang pictures added to the post

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile there is no such an option

Comment: @Davis it's postname or set up your own custom structure

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile its not working. In template I am using `get_category_link($category->term_id); ` to get the link but it returns slug instead of name